# Remapping default bindings vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

When I press `ctrl`+`h` in insert mode vim cuts character to the left. I have tried:

- `noremap h <NOP>`
- `inoremap h <NOP>`
- `noremap <C-h> <NOP>`
- `inoremap <C-h> <NOP>`

to disable this behavior, butt none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the final solution in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936461/inoremap-not-working

The root cause was `set paste` in my vimrc.